# ITIL or CMMI on IT department Management?

Tags: cmmi, itil

I want to organize our IT department which is responsible from software development, system administration and hardware maintaenance basically. I thought that I have to begin with writing processes and instructions. Since we begin from the beginning benefiting from a standard can result with better organised structure of IT department. For this purpose I have been trying to find some processes over Internet which is written according to ITIL principles. But I couldn't find any yet :( Do ypu think that I should continue my search with CMMI? Which one more fits to system administration and IT department management? I know that CMMI is more related to Quality but I think that it is not composed of only quality. Thank you for your time...

Ferda

Comment: Your question is on topic on the [ITIL Stackexchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89073/itil?referrer=x5X3k7r_NAmvg4ZTdjTOlw2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the named process frameworks, i.e. CMMI and ITIL focus on quality. Here are my comparison:

1. CMMI standards and guidelines are free, however you should pay for ITIL documents.
2. Being free, there are lots of papers and articles on CMMI. you cannot find such info on ITIL as well.
3. CMMI and its parents, i.e. CMM date back to more than 25 years ago, and it has been mature in these days. But, you cannot find such history on ITIL.
4. Behind CMMI, you can find CMU and DoD that are more credible compared to the one behind ITIL.

Having mentioned these items, I propose you CMMI rather than ITIL. There are lots of similar frameworks such as COBIT and TickIT that I think CMMI is more mature than them.